# cannot return /user/docker when trying to route a function on Node js

Tags: python, node.js, scripting

I'm currently coding a website, on one of its pages there is a button that has to launch a python script taking 3 arguments (modif, id and type). My problem is that with the following code the web site returns me :

`Cannot GET /users/docker`

Here is the button in the html page :

```
<a class="btn yellow_btn" href="/users/docker?modif=modification&id=1&type=mysql">Valider</a>
```

Here is the route in my server.js :

```
app.get("/users/docker", function(req, res, modif, id, type){
  console.log(modif);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(type);
 
  const pythonInfo = spawn('python3', ['/home/flag-trader/script-python-site.py', modif, id, type]);
 
  res.render("listCTF.ejs"); 
  }
);
```

The python script is ok, I've tried it manually. What's more i've managed to launch it on the website by switching the button to a form that I've set hidden but it's kind of ugly and I wanna do it the proper way.
I'm kind of new with all the Nodejs stuff please try not to lose me, i'm pretty sure my code is missing just a few things to work. Thx a lot.

Comment: what does the server logs when you call that endpoint?
also, as far as I know, `modif`, `id` and `type` should be retrieved from `req`, not received as params in your callback function.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late but the servers im working on were closed during xmas hollydays. I've checked the servers logs and they say nothing.. 
can you tell me more about how i can retrieve my parameters from req ?

Comment: hey! I was on vacation, check this out to get values from the request: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req
based on the response you are getting, you are indeed hitting the nodejs server, the problem is that you seem to be getting 404 from that url.

Comment: also, try to add a default route, so all calls that not hit `/users/docker` go there, then you can log whatever you want

Comment: mmmh it might works but i don't want anyone to spam this button by entering invalid routes in the navbar..

Comment: yeah I mean this only for testing purposes, then you can remove it